# How to remove active elements of a pdf in Java?

Tags: java, pdf, sanitization

I would like to remove any active elements from PDF files uploaded to my application. I have done some research and have come to the keywords sanitization and flattening. I'm not sure these terms are synonyms to what I need. Can anybody point me in a direction they used before?

Comment: Which PDF library do you want to use?

Comment: I know there are a few out there, but I don't have any preference.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *active elements*? Only javascript? Or also link or other annotations? What about forms, be they AcroForm or XFA?

Comment: @mkl from my current understanding, the best definition for _active elements_ has been offered by Rave in the second reply in this thread (https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat/how-do-i-remove-active-content-from-a-pdf-file/td-p/6703836).

Comment: I don't see a definition there, just an example, "Java-Script embedded in a PDF file." As indicated above there are other obvious kinds of active elements in PDFs, too. And other such kinds can be malicious, too, e.g. links to spam or scam sites. At the same time, though, removing JavaScript or other active elements may render some documents useless, even misleading. Therefore my question, how restrictive do you want to be, what do you want to remove?

Comment: OK, I see your point. The task calls for "removing active elements of pdf". And this is an investigation, so let's say I need or want to remove all active elements, regardless of rendering some documents useless.

Comment: Ok, that means removing all PDF annotations and all JavaScript. For those annotations with an appearance content stream one can make these appearance streams form XObjects and reference those XObjects from the page content. That is called "flattening". Concerning JavaScript code one has to look at a number of locations which may contain JavaScript actions and clear them. Actually other actions also are "active", so one should remove all actions. Well, so this describes what to do, now we're back to the original question which PDF library to use. Are there any restrictions for you?

Comment: At this point, there are no restrictions.